# What is the difference between JSON Web Signature (JWS) and JSON Web Token (JWT)?

Tags: rest, jwt, restful-authentication, http-token-authentication

I've been coding a [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services) service in Java. This is what I've understood till now:

Token authorization is done using *JSON Web Tokens (JWT)* which have three parts: the header, the payload, and the secret (shared between the client and the server).

I understood this concept and stumbled over *JSON Web Signature (JWS)* while reading about JWT.

JWS also is an encoded entity similar to JWT having a header, payload, and a shared secret.

What is the difference between the two concepts, namely JWT and JWS? And if they are alike technically, then what's the difference in their *implementation*?

This is the first time I'm working with token-based authentication, so it's possible I've misunderstood the concept altogether.

P.S.: I learned about JWS while browsing through the examples on [this website](http://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt).

Answer (score 86, accepted):

JWT actually **uses** JWS for its signature. From the [specification's abstract](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519):

> JSON Web Token (JWT) is a compact, URL-safe means of representing
> claims to be transferred between two parties. The claims in a JWT are
> encoded as a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) object that is used as
> the payload of a JSON Web Signature (JWS) structure or as the
> plaintext of a JSON Web Encryption (JWE) structure, enabling the
> claims to be digitally signed or MACed and/or encrypted.

So a JWT is a JWS structure with a JSON object as the payload. Some optional keys (or claims) have been defined such as `iss`, `aud`, `exp`, etc.

This also means that its integrity protection is not just limited to shared secrets, but public/private key cryptography can also be used.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. So where does my user info go, if the payload contains the claim set? Can you show me an example?

Comment: please take a look at the examples in Appendix A in the spec here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token-32

Comment: The claims will have the user info. Here's an example in code with comments talking about what is going on https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/JWT%20Examples

Comment: @HansZ. the examples in Appendix A only show JWT. I'm interested in seeing an example of a JWS so I can see the difference between a JWT and a JWS.

Answer (score 26):

To put it simply, **JWT (JSON Web Token)** is a way of representing claims, which are name-value pairs, into a JSON object. The [JWT specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) defines a set of standard claims to be used or transferred between two parties.

On the other hand, **JWS (JSON Web Signature)** is a mechanism for transferring a JWT payload between two parties with a guarantee for *integrity*. The [JWS specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515) defines multiple ways of signing (for example, HMAC or digital signature) the payload and multiple ways of serializing the content to transfer across the network.

Answer (score 1):

According to the spec ([RFC7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519)) there are multiple varieties of JWT:

- *Unsecured JWTs* only have two parts (header and claims), that is, they omit any crypto part. The header contains `"alg":"none"`.
- Claims encoded as the payload of a **JWS** (i.e., cryptographically signed). This is the typical three-part signed JWT.
- Claims encoded as the plaintext of a **JWE** (i.e., encrypted). This has more components (header, encrypted key, randomisation, ciphertext, integrity..).
- Nested JWTs...

Therefore a JWT can be *either* a JWS **or** a JWE, depending on what FORM of crypto is used to protect the integrity of the claims. That is, a JWT can either be signed or encrypted (or both, or neither); not every JWT is a JWS.

Conversely (by [RFC7515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515)), a JWS can be used to protect the integrity of any binary payload (not only of JSON formatted claims) so not every JWS is a JWT either.