# Is signature in JWT base64 encoded?

Tags: jwt, base64, hmacsha256

I am learning about JWTs and the way I have understood about JWTs is as follows (assuming we are using `HS256` signing algorithm):

```js
// pseudo code
HEADER = Base64Encoded(headerJSON)
PAYLOAD = Base64Encoded(payloadJSON)
SIGNATURE = HMACSHA256(`${HEADER}.${PAYLOAD}`, secret)
```

and finally JWT string is generated by joining all of the above:

```js
JWT = `${HEADER}.${PAYLOAD}.${SIGNATURE}`
```

So, `HEADER` and `PAYLOAD` both are base64 encoded, but I am not sure about signature. I think we need `SIGNATURE` to be base64 encoded as well as it will be safe for HTTP headers to include.

If it is encoded then do we do it manually? or `HMACSHA256` algo automatically returns encoded version? 
On the other hand if it is not encoded, then why do we not require it?

Comment: Yes, the signature is Base64URL encoded, see [RFC7515, section 3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7515#section-3).

Comment: Thanks a lot @jps for your input, I digged more into the specifications and wrote an answer with reasoning since I was a little confused between JWT and JWS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JWTs are defined by RFC7519 standard and its [Section 1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-1) describes:

> [...] JWTs encode claims
> to be transmitted as a JSON object that is used as the
> payload of a **JSON Web Signature (JWS) structure** or as the
> plaintext of a JSON Web Encryption (JWE) structure [...] JWTs are **always represented using the JWS Compact Serialization** or the JWE Compact Serialization.

So a JWT is either represented as the *JWS Compact Serialization* or *JWE Compact Serialization*.

For non-encrypted JWT tokens, we use JWS structure which is defined by RFC7515 standard. Hence *JWS Compact Serialization* is used which is described in its [Section-3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7515#section-3.1)

> In the JWS Compact Serialization, a JWS is represented as the concatenation:
>
> ```js
> BASE64URL(UTF8(JWS Protected Header)) || '.' ||
> BASE64URL(JWS Payload) || '.' ||
> BASE64URL(JWS Signature)
> ```

An encoding example with `HMACSHA256` signing algorithm is also provided in the [Appendix-A.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7515#appendix-A.1)

> [...] Running the HMAC SHA-256 algorithm on the JWS Signing Input with this key yields this JWS Signature octet sequence:
>
> ```
> [116, 24, 223, 180, 151, 153, 224, 37, 79, 250, 96, 125, 216, 173,
> 187, 186, 22, 212, 37, 77, 105, 214, 191, 240, 91, 88, 5, 88, 83,
> 132, 141, 121]
> ```
>
> Encoding this JWS Signature as BASE64URL(JWS Signature) gives this value:
>
> ```
> dBjftJeZ4CVP-mB92K27uhbUJU1p1r_wW1gFWFOEjXk
> ```

So **YES**, the signature is Base64 encoded as per the specification and we need to manually encode it after running the signing algorithm.

Comment: More info on [JWT vs JWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27640930/what-is-the-difference-between-json-web-signature-jws-and-json-web-token-jwt)